# transparent bridge is nat possible anyway with nftables?

Tags: nat

I two 10gb NICs(eth1,eth2) in one card configured as bridge(br0), and PC( with ubuntu 22.04)'s own nic(eth0) for accessing it, only.
I am making this a transparent bridge for filtering undesired packets using nftables, with good result (just learning it, too).

I need to make portforward too. something like:

```
chain nat {
                type nat hook prerouting priority -199; policy accept;
                meta nftrace set 1
                iif eth1 ip daddr a.b.c.d tcp dport x counter dnat to e.f.g.h:y
        }
```

I know that it is not a network standard within a bridge, bridge nat is about modifying destination mac. I read about nft has not bridge l3 ip capabilities for now.

Anyway I am asking is there any workaround, two step operations with preferably with nft.
At last, if it is not possbile with nft, can I do it with xdp/bpf or something else ?
I could not prefer this, compiling a c code for every new/modify entry with many other complications.

Thank in advance